# Как подключить стороннюю библиотеку в Symfony?

Tags: php

Как подключить стороннюю библиотеку в Symfony? Например PHPExcel или Google API.

Comment: Пример с PHPExcel по ссылке http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402839/how-to-use-phpexcel-correctly-with-symfony-2

Comment: @LANSELOT, спасибо. Сейчас попробую.